# CorePlot x axis labels

Tags: core-plot

OK, my final issue with getting my bar chart setup is how to print the X axis labels.  I tried this:

```
if let axis = graph.axisSet as? CPTXYAxisSet, xAxis = axis.xAxis {
    let dateLabels = self!.dates!.map {
        CPTAxisLabel(text: NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate($0, dateStyle: .ShortStyle, timeStyle: .NoStyle), textStyle: nil)
    }

    xAxis.axisLabels = Set(dateLabels)
}
```

I'm getting nothing displayed though.  I looked at DatePlot sample but I don't want to do what it's doing as it incorrectly assumes that a day is 86,400 seconds long, and that will break multiple times.  Also, my date offsets are in months, so that makes it even worse.  Can't I just somehow provide the already formatted date string?

Seems strange to me that "axisLabels" would be a set, since a set is not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Each axis label has a `tickLocation`. Set the tick location to the bar location for that label in the same units used in the plot space and datasource. Since the label tick location is not related to its position in the array, we can use an unordered collection like a set.

Comment: My plot space xRange was setup as `CPTPlotRange(location: 0, length: self!.dates!.count)`, and then I set ticLocation to be 0 through 11 (I have 12 dates) but still nothing is showing on the X axis.

Comment: Anything new you can suggest for me to try, Eric?